# Getting top counts in a single query in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have the following two fields:

```
`name`     `age`
"tom"      20
"tom"      20
"brad"     10
"steve"    14
"alex"     13
"alex"     11
```

I want to populate a filter panel on my Page that gives the top count per field. For example, it would look like:

```
name (top 2)
----------------
Alex (2)
Tom (2)

age (top 2)
----------------
20 (2)
10 (1)
```

Normally I would do this with two queries:

```
SELECT name, count(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY name ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 2;
SELECT age, count(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY age ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 2
```

However, there may literally be hundreds of columns, so I do not want to do 100s of queries just to load the Filters panel. Is there a way to do the above in a single query? It needs to be exact results, so it cannot use something like `APPROX_TOP_COUNT` (unless you can specify 100% precision) on it.

How would I construct the above query?

Perhaps the following query would work, but how do I ensure that the results and counts will be exact?

```
select APPROX_TOP_COUNT(name, 2), APPROX_TOP_COUNT(age, 2) from `mytable`
```

The reason I need exact is because there may be financial data here, and for example, I need to give an exact count of "units sold" or something similar in the side panel.

Comment: I'm confused.  What do your rows look like?  You have six values for `name` but only three for `age`.

Comment: i have the same question

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've updated the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MohammedSherifKK I've updated the question.

Comment: what is the size of the dataset?  
are you more concerned with the amount of queries or execution times?  
can u cache the result set between page views?  
can u pre-aggregate / populate it?

Comment: @EladAmit I think it would be to do it in one query.

Comment: in that case you can generate the queries programatically and send them in one job via a UNION ALL op
e.g. `(select 'name' as type, name ,count(1) from mytable group by 1 order by 2 desc) union all (select 'age' as type, age,count(1) from mytable group by 1 order by 2 desc)`

Comment: @EladAmit agreed, that seems the simplest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  ARRAY(SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, r'\(0*', '(') FROM t.names name ORDER BY name DESC) names,
  ARRAY(SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(age, r'\(0*', '(') FROM t.ages age ORDER BY age DESC) ages
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 2) names,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT age ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 2) ages
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      CONCAT('(', SUBSTR(CONCAT('00000', CAST(COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY name) AS STRING)), -5), ') ', name) name,
      CONCAT('(', SUBSTR(CONCAT('00000', CAST(COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY age) AS STRING)), -5), ') ', CAST(age AS STRING)) age
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
) t
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'tom' name, 20 age UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tom', 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'brad', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'steve', 14 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'alex', 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'alex', 11 
)
SELECT
  ARRAY(SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, r'\(0*', '(') FROM t.names name ORDER BY name DESC) names,
  ARRAY(SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(age, r'\(0*', '(') FROM t.ages age ORDER BY age DESC) ages
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 2) names,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT age ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 2) ages
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      CONCAT('(', SUBSTR(CONCAT('00000', CAST(COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY name) AS STRING)), -5), ') ', name) name,
      CONCAT('(', SUBSTR(CONCAT('00000', CAST(COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY age) AS STRING)), -5), ') ', CAST(age AS STRING)) age
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
) t
```

with result

```
Row     names       ages     
1       (2) tom     (2) 20   
        (2) alex    (1) 14
```

> Update for `I'd like to have it as an array (exactly as it would be in select APPROX_TOP_COUNT(name, 2), APPROX_TOP_COUNT(age, 2) from mytable)`

See below - just two lines in outer SELECT are changed

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'tom' name, 20 age UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tom', 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'brad', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'steve', 14 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'alex', 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'alex', 11 
)
SELECT
  ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(name, r'\(\d*\) (.*)') AS value, CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(name, r'\((\d*)\)') AS INT64) AS `count`) FROM t.names name ORDER BY name DESC) names,
  ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(age, r'\(\d*\) (.*)') AS value, CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(age, r'\((\d*)\)') AS INT64) AS `count`) FROM t.ages age ORDER BY age DESC) ages
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 2) names,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT age ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 2) ages
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      CONCAT('(', SUBSTR(CONCAT('00000', CAST(COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY name) AS STRING)), -5), ') ', name) name,
      CONCAT('(', SUBSTR(CONCAT('00000', CAST(COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY age) AS STRING)), -5), ') ', CAST(age AS STRING)) age
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
) t
```

with result

```
Row names.value names.count ages.value  ages.count   
1   tom         2           20          2    
    alex        2           14          1
```

Comment: Is there a way to grab it without concatenating the string?

Comment: What do you mean? Please clarify. Do you mean you don’t need the counts in output

Comment: I do, but I'd like to have it as an array (exactly as it would be in `select APPROX_TOP_COUNT(name, 2), APPROX_TOP_COUNT(age, 2) from `mytable``).

Comment: sure. easily. i was targeting output based on example you provided in your question. will update/add to my answer